# If checkbox is true then delete whole row and checkbox in vba

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, rows

I am trying to create a macro that helps me delete all the rows in which the checkbox is TRUE. So far I created one that deletes all the rows (in which checkboxes are TRUE) however the checkboxes are still there. I attached two photos of how the table looks like and how I want it to be look like after running the macro.

Table from which I would like to delete row 2 and 4 with the checkbox
[image]

desired table after running the macro
[image]

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKkLe.png)

Comment: You can avoid the checkboxes at all and use the worksheet_selectionchange-event to insert e.g. an x into a column - if you are interested in this solution I will add an according answer.

Comment: Please do not add code as a screenshot - copy and paste as *text* and then use for matting button to format as code.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Ike! I would be interested in as well.

Comment: Tim Williams, I will keep in mind, next time I will do so, sorry for making it difficult to copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I see (and default naming conventions), you're using standard forms checkboxes (i.e. not ActiveX).
Given that, the following code will do what you want.

```
Sub RemoveCheckedRows()
    
    Dim ctCB As CheckBox

''' Process all checkboxes in the ActiveSheet
    For Each ctCB In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    
    ''' If the checkbox is checked, remove the row it's in and the checkbox itself
        If ctCB = 1 Then
            ctCB.TopLeftCell.EntireRow.Delete
            ctCB.Delete
        End If
        
    Next ctCB

End Sub
```

Notes:

1. You need to ensure the top left corner of each checkbox is actually within a cell in the row to which it refers
2. You also need to ensure the Checkbox properties are set to 'Move but don't size will cells'

   - This is the default state when adding checkboxes. Still, never hurts to make sure
3. You don't need to link a cell to the checkbox value (though you still can if you want)

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes (and other objects) are not a child of the cell they are hovering over, so you would have to remove them manually.

Without your source code it's a bit of a guess how you could implement this best, but here's a pseude code;

```
'Loop through checkboxes
for each obj in ActiveWorksheet.OLEObjects
   If obj.Object.Value = True Then
        'Your code to remove the rows
        ...

        'Remove the checkbox itself
        obj.Delete
    End If
next obj
```

Next you have to make sure that the subsequent checkboxes shift up when you delete rows. To achieve this make sure that you select "Move with cells" option under the position properties for each checkbox.

Comment: First of all, Thanks for your help! Sorry, I did not provide my code but I edited my question up there so you will see my code within your code. But as you can see in the first line debug must be done for some reason. Do you have an idea what can be wrong?

Comment: "debug must be done for some reason" - you will have got an error message: what was it?

Comment: Has a basic bug: ActiveWorksheet should be Activesheet. However (ddomi), either way, will only work if your checkboxes are ActiveX controls (which, based on the naming, I don't think they are).